# Slice knot and rational ball

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

I'm trying to understand the proof of the following classical theorem of Casson and Gordon.

**Theorem ([CG86](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/cassgord.pdf)):** If $K$ is a smoothly slice knot in $S^3$, then its double branched cover $\Sigma(K)$ bounds a rational homology ball.

I'm lost in the algebraic topological arguments. Is there anyone explain the key steps of the proof or suggest an alternative (possibly easier) proof of it?

Comment: The rational ball is given by the 2-fold branched cover of $D^4$ along the slice disc right? The aim of the argument is to show that this branched cover is a rational ball. Is there a partial confusing step?